# How do I produce a "+" or "-" in the exponent?

Tags: pdftex

For example I want to write `$vcs^{+}_{G_F}$` but I actually do not know how to write the `+` in the exponent, so LaTeX can parse it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's wrong when you type `$vcs^{+}_{G_F}$`? If you use some standard text editor, all you have to do is type the characters exactly as you have given them.

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Do you try to test your math term? It works fine. So, it is not clear what is the problem

Comment: But if you have a single variable `vcs` (and not multiplying the three variables `v`, `c`, and `s`), you should change that to `\mathit{vcs}` (the spacing will be different).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am working with TexWorks and it was somehow not able to parse $vcs^{+}$, but it is able to parse $vcs^+$. So I fixed the problem. Somehow it is expecting more content inside of the exponent if I use {} to denote a block for the exponent.

Comment: Also thanks for your tip @Teepeemm!

Comment: TexWorks is a front end.  Even if its syntax highlighting is confused by `vcs^{+}`, it should still typeset correctly.

Comment: Hmmm, I also use TeXworks as my editor (on a MacTeX2022 system), and I experience no difficulties whatsoever with `$vcs^{+}_{G_F}$`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$vcs^{+}_{G_F}$
\end{document}
```

produces this output:

[image]

It looks ok to me, and did not generate any error messages.